# How to set up cross domain tracking between a root and subdomain that each have their own GTM and GA containers

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, google-tag-manager

I have ads pointing to our root domain "mydomain.com" and the conversions occur on our subdomain "convert.mydomain.com". I lose any source channel attribution and any conversion/goal tracking once they leave the subdomain.

Here are the facts:

- Both domains have their own separate Google Tag Manager (GTM) containers
- Both domains have their own Google Analytics (GA) profiles. convert.mydomain.com has both GA profiles tracking in its GTM container.
- convert.mydomain.com GTM sends a "cart add" conversion event to the convert.mydomain.com GA, but not the mydomain.com GA.
- The GA goal for a "cart checkout" conversion on convert.mydomain.com is a destination goal which tracks on convert.mydomain.com and mydomain.com GA accounts.

Question:

1. How do I track ad conversions and source channel if the users enter at mydomain.com and convert at convert.mydomain.com?
2. How does Google Ads know if a person who entered mydomain.com from a Google Ad converted on convert.mydomain.com? (for conversion based bidding reasons)

Thanks in advance for any information on this – I am stumped!